# Is InSampleSize calculated wrong in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap

Here is the method offered by [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) from google.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
}
```

If there is a 500*500 image which required to be resized to 100*100, the result of this snippet is 4 because they use `halfWidth` and `halfHeight`. But if I understand it correctly, the result should be 8. I think the code should be modified as:

```
while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
inSampleSize *= 2;
```

Can anyone explain this? I found they had modified this code several times, but seems still wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that the image is scaled down in 2 steps: first by the highest power of 2 less than or equal to the required down-sampling factor, and then by an amount less than 2 to end up with the final requested image size.

> If there is a 500*500 image which required to be resized to 100*100, the result of this snippet is 4 because they use halfWidth and halfHeight. But if I understand it correctly, the result should be 8.

If the scale factor is 8, then a 500x500 pixel image will be scaled down to 62x62 pixels, and would then need to be scaled up to the requested size of 100x100 pixels.

As the code comment says:

> Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both height and width larger than the requested height and width.

This would be 4, because then you will end up with an image of 125x125 pixels, which is larger than the requested height and width of 100x100 pixels. The idea is that you want to end up scaling down in the last step, rather than scaling down too far and then having to scale back up and getting a blurry image.

The required down-sampling factor is 5, and the highest power of 2 less than or equal to that is 4.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation is correct. But I feel the requested size should be like a bottom line that you cannot cross. For a 700*700 image, the resampled size is 175*175 which seems too large. It's a tradeoff between blur and memory.